# TFS Build Unit Test app.config files

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, tfsbuild

I'm building ~600 projects to a flat file structure (this includes a bunch of unit test assemblies). I'm following a naming convention to easily identify unit test assemblies (.utest.dll).

TFS Build is finding the correct unit test projects to build, but it's not copying their respective app.config files to the flat file structure before trying to execute the unit tests.
What would be the easiest way of having every test use their own app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following attribute to your test method to have the app.config file deployed. 
[DeploymentItem("app.config", "targetFolder")]

Check this MSDN article for the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms182475(v=vs.120).aspx